# new operator in kernel .. strange behaviour

Tags: cuda

I was wondering if anybody can shed some light on this behaviour with the new operator within a kernel.. Following is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "cuComplex.h"
using namespace std;
__global__ void test()
{

    cuComplex *store;
    store= new cuComplex[30000];
    if (store==NULL) printf("Unable to allocate %i\n",blockIdx.y);
    delete store;
    if (threadIdx.x==10000) store->x=0.0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    float timestamp;
    cudaEvent_t event_start,event_stop;
    // Initialise


    cudaEventCreate(&event_start);
    cudaEventCreate(&event_stop);
    cudaEventRecord(event_start, 0);
    dim3 threadsPerBlock;
    dim3 blocks;
    threadsPerBlock.x=1;
    threadsPerBlock.y=1;
    threadsPerBlock.z=1;
    blocks.x=1;
    blocks.y=500;
    blocks.z=1;

    cudaEventRecord(event_start);
    test<<<blocks,threadsPerBlock,0>>>();
    cudaEventRecord(event_stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(event_stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&timestamp, event_start, event_stop);
    printf("test took  %fms \n", timestamp);
}
```

Running this on a GTX680 Cuda 5 and investigating the output one will notice that randomly memory is not allocated :( I was thinking that maybe it is because all global memory is finished but I have 2GB of memory and since the maximum amount of active blocks is 16 the amount of memory allocated with this method should at maximum be 16*30000*8=38.4x10e6.. ie around 38Mb. So what else should I consider?

Comment: The memory allocated should be `16*30000*sizeof(cuComplex)`

Comment: Also note that `threadIdx.x` would never be equal to `10000`

Comment: This is possibly just memory fragmentation on the runtime heap. Have you tried increasing the runtime heap size a bit?

Comment: Yes you are right but cuComplex is only 8 bytes so the sum just goes up to 32Mb.. still there is more plenty of memory available (2GB). regarding threadIdx.x==1000 that is just to fool the compiler and not let it ignore the store variable

Comment: @tolanmies.. i inserted in the code cudaDeviceSetLimit(cudaLimitMallocHeapSize,30000*8*400); and it worked... but how do I calculate to what size I need to increase this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is related with the size of the heap used by the malloc() and free() device system calls. See `section 3.2.9 Call Stack` and `appendix B.16.1 Heap Memory Allocation` in the NVIDIA CUDA C Programming Guide for more details.

Your test will work if you set the heap size to fit your kernel requirement

```
    cudaDeviceSetLimit(cudaLimitMallocHeapSize, 500*30000*sizeof(cuComplex));
```

Comment: But this will eat all my memory...and is not really required since only allocations from 6 blocks are possible... Is there a way to have finer calculation of the limit?

Comment: Change `500` for `concurrently blocks x Streaming Multiprocessors` to get the minimum size that you need, being `SM = 8` in the gtx680 and the number of concurrent blocks depending of the kernel requirements in terms of registers or shared memory.